# How to achieve this layout in .Net Maui?

Tags: maui

I have a .Net Maui app for selling some items.

Basically items are organised this way :

- Pages

  - Categories

    - Items

I need the pages to work like tabbed pages. And inside a page there are categories summarized on the top of the page. And then items inside. And if I scroll to the bottom, the categories are moving to adapt to the current visible items.

Here is an example :

Here the page is **Boissons & Eaux** and the categories are **Jus frais & Smoothies**, **Jus et néctars** ...

[image]

And if I scroll to the bottom, the categories scroll to the right like this :

[image]

etc.

I know how to create tabbed pages. And for the categories, I'm thinking about the grouping feature of the collection view. However this doesn't seem to summarize categories separately. It just creates a header for each category as [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-7.0).

How can I get a layout similar to this?

Comment: You need to write your own custom tab control. You can use radio buttons and BindableLayout. This guy has interesting idea on the subject: https://dev.to/davidortinau/making-a-tabbar-or-segmentedcontrol-in-net-maui-54ha

Comment: @H.A.H. "This guy" is David Ortinau, Principal Program Manager at Microsoft and in charge of the .NET MAUI development, by the way ;) Very sympathetic fellow